# Get accurate scroll position before 'domready' in Internet Explorer when scroll position is restored from back button navigation or reload?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I created a minimal test case (and logged a [bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8605539/) with Microsoft that references it): https://dennishall1.github.io/pageYOffset-test/

But maybe someone out there has encountered and solved for this?

(I tried the standard `window.pageYOffset`, but I also tried a few of the 'older ways' -- `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, for example, and they didn't provide an accurate scroll position any sooner, but maybe there's another way.)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this below code `document.body.scrollTop`

Comment: That property (`document.body.scrollTop`) is not set at all in standards-mode.  I didn't explicitly specify (it's implied by the test case), but I only care about standards mode.  (Furthermore, I'd be surprised if that property was set any earlier in quirks mode than the standard property is set in standards-mode.)

Comment: Sorry,I don't know what you're going to do,but,You can choose DOCTYPE or judge mode